# Is there any criterion for proving that a general planar vector field has a periodic orbit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

We know that the Bendixon criterion (or its generalisation by Dulac) allows one to prove the nonexistence of periodic orbits of planar vector fields. I would like to know if there's a such a criterion for proving that a general planar vector field has a periodic orbit in some connected region of the plane .